# RDS (Radio Data System) support for FM Radion in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there rds support for fm radio in windows phone silverlight application?

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think so. When I last used the app it didn't display any RDS type information from the station.

Comment: But i saw it on Noklia Lumia 820 (win 8.1)